# Creating a SSRS report from 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I Have two tables in a `sql` server database.
Here's my First table,`Table1`

```
 +------------+------------------+----------------+
| Project ID | Project Manager  | Approved Hours |
+------------+------------------+----------------+
|          1 |             Mr.A |            120 |
|          2 |             Mr.B |            100 |
+------------+------------------+----------------+
```

Here's my Second Table,Table 2

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
| ProjectID | Project Manager | Personnel | Week No. | Working Hours |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
|         1 | Mr.A            | Tom       |        1 |            20 |
|         1 | Mr.A            | Tom       |        2 |            20 |
|         1 | Mr.A            | Tom       |        3 |            10 |
|         1 | Mr.A            | Harry     |        1 |            20 |
|         1 | Mr.A            | Harry     |        2 |            20 |
|         1 | Mr.A            | Harry     |        3 |            20 |
|         2 | Mr.B            | Tom       |        1 |            20 |
|         2 | Mr.B            | Tom       |        2 |            10 |
|         2 | Mr.B            | Tom       |        3 |            20 |
|         2 | Mr.B            | Harry     |        1 |            20 |
|         2 | Mr.B            | Harry     |        2 |            15 |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------+----------+---------------+
```

I would like to create a `ssrs` report that looks like this.I'm using the 2012 version.
Actual Hours being the sum of working Hours for each Project.

```
 +------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+
| Project ID | Project Manager | Approved Hours | Actual Hours |
+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+
|          1 | Mr.A            |            120 |          110 |
|          2 | Mr.B            |            100 |           85 |
+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+
```

I'm kind of new to SQL, Can I get this done with a single query.

Comment: Do a JOIN, and add GROUP BY!

Comment: Even if you are new to SQL, you should at least try a basic query and then post it so we can help you correct the issue you are having. Learn by doing and fixing, not by getting a query handed to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jarlh Suggest simply do `INNER JOIN` & `group by` as below  :

```
SELECT T.[Project ID],
       T.[Project Manager],
       T.[Approved Hours],
       SUM(T1.[Working Hours]) [Actual Hours]
FROM Table1 T
     INNER JOIN Table2 T1 ON T.[Project ID] = T1.[Project ID]
GROUP BY T.[Project ID],
         T.[Project Manager],
         T.[Approved Hours];
```

Result :

```
+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+
| Project ID | Project Manager | Approved Hours | Actual Hours |
+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+
|          1 | Mr.A            |            120 |          110 |
|          2 | Mr.B            |            100 |           85 |
+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+
```